# Altering main menu in drupal 7

Tags: routes

I am new to drupal, and i am trying to alter the code generated by my main menu. I would like to replace this :

```
<span thmr="thmr_249"><ul id="main-menu" class="links inline clearfix">
<li class="menu-227 first active"><span thmr="thmr_250"><a href="/" title="" class="active">Link1</a></span></li>
<li class="menu-377"><span thmr="thmr_251"><a href="/link2" title="Au détail">link2</a></span></li>
</ul></span>
```

By this :

```
<a class="act" href="/"><em><em>Link1</em></em></a> 
<a href="link2"><em><em>link2</em></em></a>
```

The code i have added on my page.tpl.php

```
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'))));
```

I have been looking around and found that it could be achieved by using theme_menu_link & theme_item_list in my templatye file....no success so far.

Can anyone show me the proper way to do it ? 
Thanks

Comment: you need to display your main menu as a block, then you can use theme_menu_tree() and theme_menu_link() for theming all elements.

Comment: I have added my menu code in the page.tpl.php i shown above

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unusual request, but if you want to clear main menu from `ul` anl `li` tags and print just links, you can do that in this way:

**template.php**

```
/**
 * Main menu
 * Implements theme__menu_tree().
 */
function YOURTHEME_menu_tree__main_menu($variables) {
  return $variables['tree'];
}

/**
 * Main menu
 * Implements theme__menu_link().
 */
function YOURTHEME_menu_link__main_menu(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
  $output = l('<em>' . $element['#title'] . '</em>', $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return $output . $sub_menu . "\n";
}
```

go to `admin/structure/block` and place main menu in header region (or wherever you want)

**Result**

```
<a class="active" href="/some-path"><em>Link1</em></a> 
<a href="/another-path"><em>link2</em></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change (alter) item in menu tree, including any dynamic values, before the item is rendered (not created or updated) is to use hook_translated_menu_link_alter(). This is the only hook that runs after item processing, but before item render. But, due to performance issues, it runs only on items that have $item['options']['alter'] = TRUE. So to make it work, 'alter' should be set to TRUE programmatically.

This allows not only to work around standard menu access callbacks and implement your own ones, but also change values of menu $item['href'] or any other property.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_translated_menu_link_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) {
  if ($item['menu_name'] == 'your-menu') {
    if ($item['link_title'] == 'Awesome Menu Link') {
      $item['access'] = TRUE;
      $item['href'] = 'new/link/path';
    }
    else {
      $item['access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Full discussion:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1897326#comment-9034011